# Checkout SVN; modify; upload to existing Github project

Tags: svn, git, github

I have an existing project that I've been working on and started using Subversion for version control.  Since then, I've open sourced the project on Github and used Github's documentation on the "git svn" command to translate SVN history into a git repo.

However, now I've made changes to the original project in SVN.  I'd like to checkout my changes from SVN and then push them up (merge them) to the github repository.

It seems like a lot of the documentation on "svn get" tells you how you can check out from an SVN repository and interact with it like you can a clone of a git repository, and then commit it back to the SVN repository.  But in my case, I'd like to commit it back to github... I can't seem to find an example of that.

I'm fairly familiar with SVN, but am very new to git and am still trying to get a grip on the concepts.  Does anyone have any advice on how to checkout from SVN as a git clone, and then push to github?  Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you set up an SVN remote in a git repo and a github remote, you can push/pull changes from either.

All you need to do is update your branch from SVN and now do a push to git hub. This is the easier part of using both hence why you probably don't see it discussed often.

Comment: Thanks for your response adymitruk. So do you recommend that I clone my gethub repo to a local copy first, merge the svn changes into the local copy, and then push back to the github repo?  Or should I do an SVN checkout to a local copy merge in the github changes and then push back to github?  Do I need to modify my .git/config/url setting to add a second repository or something?

Comment: Either way will work, clone the github one or the svn one. The github remote (in case you did not clone it) can be added via the git remote command. If you did it the other way, there is a git-svn command to add the svn repo as a remote.